# Replace fonts with VBA in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, fonts, powerpoint

I need to replace fonts in a Powerpoint presentation (replace function was unable to do so). I found a VBA script from Microsoft, but I don't know what to do next. anyone can help?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.fonts.replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use that line of code, it's enough to run it from the Immediate window of the Visual Basic editor. Use **Alt + F11** or **Alt + L + V** to open the VBE. The *Immediate* window is at the bottom, paste in the code and tap the Enter key to run it:
[image: VBA Editor showing Immediate window]

In case the VBA is not enough to change the font, you can perform the job with an OOXML hack. Change the file ending to .zip and expand it. Then use a text editor like NotePad++ to run a find and replace on all the files, changing

```
typeface="Time New Roman"
```

to

```
typeface="Courier"
```

Rezipping using the Windows Zip utility can be a problem, since it's easy to include the extra top-level folder that it creates, ruining the XML. Instead, use WinZip or 7Zip to rezip. Here's my introductory article about OOXML hacking: [OOXML Hacking: An Introduction](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/02/xml-hacking-an-introduction/)

Comment: Brilliant! I tested the script on a new PowerPoint document and it works, but didn't get rid of the fonts on the presentation in question so I did have to use the OOXML Hacking. That did the job, though re-zipping was only successful when done as described in your linked article.
Thanks!